# Eclipse and Window Builder Pro

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I am using Eclipse Helios with Window Builder Pro plugin for **Swing designing**. It makes my eclipse **horribly** unstable. I have very negative experiences also with **GWT designer** from same company.

It happens randomly and a lot.

Eclipse changes process state to "sleeping". I am on Ubuntu 10.10, but had problems also on Windows 7.

Does someone have same problems and possibly solution how to teach those plugins to behave? If not, please suggest some free popular Swing designer for Eclipse 3.6 (not MyEclipse or older Eclipse). I quite liked Matisse @ NetBeans.

Comment: I use it for some time and have no problems at all ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried reporting this problem on WindowBuilder forum? StackOverflow is great and all, but is no substitute for going directly to the software maker when running into problems.

http://forums.instantiations.com/viewforum.php?f=14